# One query to get parent of document with id

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have `id` of person `ObjectId("5650e94b2e62c5fbfa0ebdd1")`. How get name of its leader with one query?

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5650e94b2e62c5fbfa0ebdd1"),
    "login" : "Todd",
    "fullname" : "Eva Bailey",
    "leader" : ObjectId("5650e94b2e62c5fbfa0ebdd2"),
    "group" : ObjectId("5650e94b2e62c5fbfa0ebdbf")
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5650e94b2e62c5fbfa0ebdd2"),
    "login" : "Kennedy",
    "fullname" : "Oscar Stokes",
    "leader" : null,
    "group" : ObjectId("5650e94b2e62c5fbfa0ebdbf")
}
```

Comment: You can't mongo doesn't provide JOIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB is non relational database and does not support joins as opposed to other relational DB which defines relationship through reference keys  across tables in database.
Instead of defining references of documents across collections in MongoDB you can utilize embedded document feature of MongoDB.

Embedded documents are easy and fast

Example :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5650e94b2e62c5fbfa0ebdd1"),
    "login" : "Todd",
    "fullname" : "Eva Bailey",
    "leader" : 
    { 
       "name":"Tony Smith"
    },
    "group" : {
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I understand. This is good for historical data. I mean, leader of that person in time of creating document. But by reference I want to show that person has that exact leader now. Anyway I understand that there is no way doing that in one query